# Remove secondary frame in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Need to remove secondary frame (believed to be from adding legend to plot) from pyplot.

First off, I have already read the other Q&A's posted on similar issues. Frameon=False or frameon=0 is not working and I have recently re downloaded matplotlib. Other answers didn't quite address my specific issue. I also tried getting rid of plt.legend(), which got rid of the frame and legend. So then I tried plt.legend(frameon=False) and nothing changed.

```
#Arbitrary runnable code
from getpass import getpass
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import healpy as hp
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


with PdfPages('KimmiesHistogram.pdf') as pdf:

    mpl.rcParams['font.family']='serif'
    mpl.rcParams['font.size']=12

    fig = plt.figure(figsize= (12,12), frameon= False)

    plt.xlabel('MJD: Range')

    plt.title("MJD Ranges by Filter")

    y= [1, 2,3,45,6,4,34,76,4,34,65,23,34,3,3,9,5,5]
    y2=[1, 2,3,45,6,4,34,76,4,34,65,23,34,3,3,9,5,5]
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(132)
    ax1.set_xscale('log')
    ax1.set_yscale('linear')

    plt.hist([y,y2], bins=10, histtype='step', cumulative=1)

    plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code isn't runnable (see [mcve]) and there is no attempt to use `frameon`. In sum, this makes it completely impossible to know what problem you face.

Comment: Sorry you would need access to a large and private file for it to be runnable. And I took out the frameon from plt.legend() recently since it didnt work. I still have it above with plt.figure. The main issue is the legend, I am certain because if i take it out all together, the outer frame goes away. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: You need to *make it runnable*, by creating such [mcve]. That is forget about your secret file and use data created within the example code.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Now runnable! Please try again as I still need help!

Comment: Ok, but there is no second frame or anything that looks undesired. Can you make sure it's clear from the question what exact problem you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear as to what you really mean but I believe you are seeing the borders for 3 subplots. Please clarify your question if this is not the case.  When I run your code I get this:

[image]

If you want to remove that outer box then just specify that you want to add only 1 subplot instead of the middle of 3 subplots using `ax=fig.add_subplot(111)`. That is where your problem is. But to be honest you don't need to add a figure axis in your example to plot the data you want.

```
#Arbitrary runnable code
from getpass import getpass
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


with PdfPages('KimmiesHistogram.pdf') as pdf:

    mpl.rcParams['font.family']='serif'
    mpl.rcParams['font.size']=12

    fig = plt.figure(figsize= (12,12), frameon= False)

    plt.xlabel('MJD: Range')

    plt.title("MJD Ranges by Filter")

    y= [1, 2,3,45,6,4,34,76,4,34,65,23,34,3,3,9,5,5]
    y2=[1, 2,3,45,6,4,34,76,4,34,65,23,34,3,3,9,5,5]
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.set_xscale('log')
    ax1.set_yscale('linear')

    plt.hist([y,y2], bins=10, histtype='step', cumulative=1)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The subplot was exactly the problem! Thank you very much for the thorough answer!